# Android sensors undetected

Tags: android, kernel, sensors, rom

I ported MIUIv7 for my Archos 45 Hélium today, everything works fine except my sensors like proximity, light, compasss etc...

I tried to replace a lot of libs, but my sensors still undetected by any apps

Is it a kernel problem ?
And how to resolve it ?

Thanks